# How to export a csv in utf-8 format?

Tags: r

I am trying to export a data.frame to a csv with utf-8 encoding. I have tried generating the file with write.csv with no success and the help(write.csv) did not mention any specific advice on creating that specific output. Here is my current export line.

```
write.csv(prod_out, file="product_output.csv",append=FALSE,eol="\r")
```

Any advice you can offer is appreciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try opening a UTF8 connection:

```
con<-file('filename',encoding="UTF-8")
write.csv(...,file=con,...)
```

Comment: I think it should better be "UTF-8". From the manual: `Encoding names "utf8", "mac" and "macroman" are not portable, and not supported on all current R platforms. "UTF-8" is portable and "macintosh" is the official (and most widely supported) name for ‘Mac Roman’.`

Comment: Thank you!! Worked for me with .txt files as well.

Comment: Hi @mbq what comes in place of dotted line?

Answer (score 77):

This question is pretty old - I guess things have changed a lot since 2010. Anyway, I just came across this post and I happen to know the solution. You just add `fileEncoding = "UTF-8"` option directly to `write.csv`.

Answer (score 8):

You can try this solution:

```
write.csv(data,"data.csv",fileEncoding = "UTF-8")
```

Comment: Will the argument 'fileEncoding = "UTF-8"' also work for 'write_csv()' or perhaps a similar argument to specify variable-length character encoding?