# R code to split big table into smaller .txt files and save to computer?

Tags: r

I have a huge .txt file named SDN_1 with more than 1 million rows. I would like to split this file into smaller .txt files (10,000 rows each) using R.

I used this code to load the file into R:

```
SDN_1 <- read.csv("C:/Users/JHU/Desktop/rfiles/SDN_1.csv", header=FALSE)
```

Then I used this code to split the table:

```
chunk <- 10000
n     <- nrow(SDN_1)
r     <- rep(1:ceiling(n/chunk),each=chunk)[1:n]
d     <- split(SDN_1,r)
```

Next I would like to save the output of the split function into separate files as .txt and encode as UTF8. The files need to be named in the following format: test_YYYMMDD_HHMMSS.txt

I'm new to R and any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:
Hack-R suggested the code below to create the .csv file. The code below worked once then started giving me the error message below:

Code Hack-R suggested:

```
n <- 1
for(i in d){
con <- file(paste0("file",n,"_", gsub("-
","",gsub(":","",gsub("","_",Sys.time()))), "_",".csv"),encoding="UTF-8")
write.csv(tmp, file = con)
n <- n + 1
}
```

The error message I'm getting:

```
Error in is.data.frame(x) : object 'tmp' not found
```

Comment: The answer below works but it doesn't seem to work all the time. First time I ran it, it worked and the .csv file were created in this folder (C:\Users\JHU\Documents). I tried to change work directory using setwd(C:\Users\JHU\Desktop\rfiles) to download the generated .csv files in rfiles the I got the error "Error in is.data.frame(x) : object 'tmp' not found ".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the code you already have:

```
SDN_1 <- mtcars # this represents your csv, to make it reproducible

chunk <- 10 # scaled it down for the example
n     <- nrow(SDN_1)
r     <- rep(1:ceiling(n/chunk),each=chunk)[1:n]
d     <- split(SDN_1,r)

n <- 1 # this part is optional
for(i in d){
  con <- file(paste0("file",n,"_", gsub("-","",gsub(":","",gsub(" ","_",Sys.time()))), "_",".csv"),encoding="UTF-8")
  write.csv(tmp, file = con)  
  n <- n + 1
}
```

More generally, let's say `a` and `b` represent the splits of a larger object or any collection of objects in the environment you want to write out programmatically:

```
a <- "a"
b <- "b"
```

You can get a vector containing their names:

```
files <- ls()
```

Then loop through and programmatically write them to a UTF-8 encoded csv file as follows, appending the date and time in the format you requested:

```
for(i in files){
  tmp <- get(i)
  con <- file(paste0(tmp,"_", gsub("-","",gsub(":","",gsub(" ","_",Sys.time()))), "_",".csv"),encoding="UTF-8")
  write.csv(tmp, file = con)  
}
```

I used `Sys.time()` for the timestamp with nested `gsub()`s to format the way you wanted. I encoded the file to UTF-8 as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792846/how-to-export-a-csv-in-utf-8-format).

Comment: Hack-R- thanks for your answer. First time tried to run the code it worked. Then when I tried to run it again it started given me this error " Error in is.data.frame(x) : object 'tmp' not found". Any suggestions why?

Comment: Ok, I noticed I get the error when I try to change the word directory using setwd(). Would it be possible to change the work directory?

Comment: @Curious Where are you trying to change the working directory? I need some context. Normally the rules say not to edit your question or add details after answers are submitted, but in this case I'm going to suggest you add the directory changing to the question and I'll update my answer accordingly. *Note* if you're just trying to save the files to a different directory you can just specify that with the file name when you use `file()`.

Comment: Thank you wasn't trying to change the original question just wanted to change work directory before running the code to select the folder where I want the .csv files to be saved. First time I ran the code, .csv file were created in this folder (C:\Users\JHU\Documents). I tried to change work directory using setwd(C:\Users\JHU\Desktop\rfiles) to download the generated .csv files in rfiles folder then I got the error message. I changed the directory back to (C:\Users\JHU\Downloads) and the code worked once and started seeing the error message again.

Comment: @Curious So it's working now then? Sorry I had a little trouble following. If it's working that's great. If it's not please put the code and full error messages in the question so that I can understand the problem.