# How to output a file with Chinese Character into .csv file that's compatible with excel?

Tags: r, excel, csv, utf-8

I want to export the data.frame with character vector **in Chinese**.
I have tried to output it into text file, it works perfectly with the following code

```
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "zh_cn.utf-8")
data<-data.frame(ID=c('小李','小王','小宗'),number=c(1:3))
write.table(data,'test.txt',quote=F,row.names=F,sep='\t')
```

But when I tried to use the `write.csv`, if I use excel to open the data file, the Chinese part of the data is not correct for the output test.csv, see the figure below for details.

```
write.csv(data,'test.csv',row.names=F)
```

[image]

I have found a similar post on stackoverflow, but failed to figure out how to cope with my case. [How to export a csv in utf-8 format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792846/how-to-export-a-csv-in-utf-8-format).

Is there any solution that can output the data file that is compatible with excel?

Comment: How is it incorrect? What's your OS and locale? Can you edit with some sample data that reproduces the issue?

Comment: My OS is Mavericks(10.10.5), have edited the question to make it clearer and reproducible.

Comment: You have not described the manner in which you are viewing this and as a result we cannot determine what font the viewing program might be using. Seeing your edit, my comment is "Omigod, he's using Excel!"

Comment: Good to point out that! then how I can solve this?

Comment: That's an Excel import issue, not an R issue. You could write directly to Excel format with something like `openxlsx::write.xlsx(data, 'test.xlsx')`, which would avoid the issue.