# write.csv with encoding utf 8 in R

Tags: r, csv, xlsx

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12Nuf.png)I used this code to save a csv file as utf 8 in R, but it doesnt work.
please help me

write.csv(zan,"C:/Users/ali/Desktop/payani/zan.csv",fileEncoding = "UTF-8")

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean exactly here? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to export a csv in utf-8 format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792846/how-to-export-a-csv-in-utf-8-format)